# Badge "Vox Populi" is improperly described

Tags: feature-request, badges, votes

The "Vox Populi" badge is improperly described. It should say "question and answer votes" instead of just "votes", since comment votes are not counted towards the Vox Populi badge.

> "Use the maximum 40 votes in a day" to "Use the maximum 40 question and answer votes in a day"

Answer (score 7):

In general, an unadorned reference to "votes" means question and answer votes. The high prominence in importance to the site of up-voting and down-voting posts means this type of voting is almost always what someone means when they refer to voting here. When comment votes are meant, or voting in a moderator election for that matter, the distinction is either made explicitly or is obvious from context. In the absence of any other qualifier, it's natural to infer the meaning, and I don't think there's a need to make it explicit. Note, too, that "the maximum 40 votes" clearly applies to content up-votes/down-votes, as that is the only type of voting to which a (specifically) 40 vote per day limit applies.

I think the usage is clear enough that no change is needed, and wouldn't particularly expect the developers (the official SE folks who would have to change this) to think this is something they should prioritize above other changes.  So I wouldn't hold your breath expecting this to happen. :)